Counter in newcommand does not reset and strange counter increment in tabularray
I ran into some issues using counters in \newcommand and tblr.

When I put the counter in a \newcommand, it does not reset when the anothercounter is stepped.
The other issue is that tblr increases the current value of \thecounter by some amounts larger than 1.

How to make these work as expected?
below is the code to reproduce my result
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[fontsize=14pt]{fontsize}

\geometry{ a4paper, left=20mm, right=20mm, top=20mm, bottom=20mm }

\newcounter{RomanCount}
\newcounter{ArabicCount}
\newcommand{\romanitem}{\stepcounter{RomanCount}\Roman{RomanCount}. }
\newcommand{\arabicitem}{\stepcounter{ArabicCount}\arabic{ArabicCount}. }

\newcounter{counter1}
\newcounter{counter2}[counter1]

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \textbf{TEST COUNTER IN COMMAND}
\end{center}

\noindent\textbf{Category \romanitem}\par
item \arabicitem\par
item \arabicitem\par
\noindent\textbf{Category \romanitem}\par
item \arabicitem\par
item \arabicitem\par
\begin{tblr}{ width=\linewidth, colspec={|Q[30mm,c,m]|X[l,b]|} }
    \hline
    & {
        \textbf{Category \romanitem}\par
        item \arabicitem\par
        item \arabicitem\par
    }\\
    \hline
\end{tblr}
\noindent\textbf{Category \romanitem}\par
item \arabicitem\par
item \arabicitem\par
\begin{tblr}{ width=\linewidth, colspec={|Q[30mm,c,m]|X[l,b]|} }
    \hline
    {
        \textbf{Category \romanitem}\par
        item \arabicitem\par
        item \arabicitem\par
    } &\\
    \hline
\end{tblr}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|X|}
    \hline
    {
        \textbf{Category \romanitem}
    } &\\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}

\begin{center}
    \textbf{TEST STANDALONE COUNTER}
\end{center}

\stepcounter{counter1}
\noindent Category \Roman{counter1}\par
item \stepcounter{counter2}\arabic{counter2}\par
item \stepcounter{counter2}\arabic{counter2}\par
\stepcounter{counter1}
\noindent Category \Roman{counter1}\par
item \stepcounter{counter2}\arabic{counter2}\par
item \stepcounter{counter2}\arabic{counter2}\par

\end{document}

and the screenshot


Update 1:
From samcarter-is-at-topanswers-xyz's comment using \UseTblrLibrary{counter} do solve the issue with tblr "randomly" increasing the value of the counter.

Update 2: thanks to Paul Gaborit, I found a stupid mistake. I should use newcounter{ArabicCount}[RomanCount] instead of just newcounter{ArabicCount}

You might want to have a look at the tabularray counter library: \UseTblrLibrary{counter}

The material is probably typeset several times in order to make measurements, this of course gives issues with macros that steps counters.

@daleif I'm quite new to Latex so I don't know how to fix that.

Use \newcounter{ArabicCount}[RomanCount] instead of \newcounter{ArabicCount}...

@PaulGaborit damn, I forgot that part. Thank you so much!

Here are the solutions from the comments:

To deal with the tblr, just use \UseTblrLibrary{counter}
I made a mistake when declare the new counter. It should be \newcounter{ArabicCount}[RomanCount] instead of just \newcounter{ArabicCount}

